# Pandas 1.3.3 ValueError: Columns must be same length as key (no duplicated columns and same shape result)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have recently updated pandas to version **1.3.3** (**in version 1.2.0 this issue works perfectly**)

I am trying to do the following:

```
self._df[cts.NUMERIC_COLS] = self._df[cts.NUMERIC_COLS].apply(pd.to_numeric,                                                                      errors='coerce')
```

where `cts.NUMERIC_COLS` is a list of column names that should be parsed.

I've checked that my dataframe has no duplicated columns and I am getting the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3641, in _setitem_array
    self[k1] = value[k2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3602, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3729, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

When executing that line:

```
self._df[cts.NUMERIC_COLS].shape >> (1142, 58)
self._df[cts.NUMERIC_COLS].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').shape >> (1142, 58)`
```

I've tried different approaches but without succeed. I am doing something wrong? Has it happened to anyone too?

Thank you to all in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a small sample DataFrame and NUMERIC_COLS for which this error is reproduced?